# Sequence of Functions Uniformally converging to $0$ method of proof

Tags: real-analysis

I am starting to learn about point-wise and uniform convergence. I know uniform is stronger because it only depends on $\epsilon$ while point-wise depends on $x$. I was wondering if my proof is adequate as well as any further comments on the subject is appreciated.

$\{\frac{x}{1+nx}\}$ on $(0,1)$

**proof**

$| f_n(x) - f_n | = | \frac{x}{1+nx} - 0| < \frac{x}{nx} = \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$

Thus $f_n(x)$ is uniformly continuous to $0$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|f_n(x) - 0| = |\frac{x}{1+nx}| < \frac{1}{n}$$

Tells you that $f_n$ converges to $0$ uniformly on $(0,1)$.

If $1+nx \neq 0$, that is $x \neq -\frac{1}{n}$, then the uniform convergence still holds. So actually $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ is also true.